# Angular Front end with Azure AD and Java Rest Services

Tags: java, angular, rest, maven, azure-active-directory

**Current Model**
I have one Angular application that calls a Java rest service (not a spring boot application) that have multiple rest end points. Initially the login will be called using username and password to acquire a JSESSIONID and this id will be passed in Authorization header of all subsequent rest calls.

**New Model**
Now I need to change the login scenario using Azure AD.
Angular will call the AAD login and this is working by registering the app as a SPA in Azure. Now how to implement the Rest calls flow using the token.

Do I need to register the Rest API also in Azure?
Is there a way to validate the token in java back end manually.?

---

Rest application Java - most of the samples uses Spring or spring boot. Is there any samples other than spring / spring security.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best practice is to register the API and UI as a separate application in Azure AD.

You will have to grant the web application permissions to the web API and request an access token for it. Here is a good reading (the article is about Azure AD B2C, but it is the same for Azure AD):
[Configure authentication in a sample single-page application](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)

Comment: Thanks @Martin, i will try. and update

Comment: How do we do it without registering the web API. How does it work?

Comment: As mentioned, you should register the API because then you request an access token for it. The ugly option would be to use the UI App registration within your API - but please don't do that.#